# ORACLE SQL, I don't know how to use SUM() here

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Table `TRANSACTION`:

| TRANS_VALUE | USER ID | TRANS_TYPE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 15 | 1 | 1 |
| 20 | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 15 | 3 | 1 |
| 20 | 3 | 1 |

I need to get to this:

| USER | SUM(TRANS_TYPE_1) | SUM(TRANS_TYPE_2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 25 |
| 2 | 5 | 20 |
| 3 | 35 | NULL |
|  |  |  |

Can someone help me?

I tried this but sadness

```
SELECT
    user_id AS "USER 
    SUM(trans_value)
FROM 
    TRANSACTION
WHERE 
    trans_value = 1
GROUP BY
    user_id
ORDER BY 1;
```

I need to get to this

| USER | SUM(TRANS_TYPE_1) | SUM(TRANS_TYPE_2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 25 |
| 2 | 5 | 20 |
| 3 | 35 | NULL |
|  |  |  |

Comment: sorry...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       SUM(CASE trans_type_id WHEN 1 THEN trans_value END) AS sum_trans_type_1,
       SUM(CASE trans_type_id WHEN 2 THEN trans_value END) AS sum_trans_type_2
FROM   transaction
GROUP BY user_id
```

or `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   transaction
PIVOT (
  SUM(trans_value)
  FOR trans_type_id IN (
    1 AS sum_trans_type_1,
    2 AS sum_trans_type_2
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE transaction (TRANS_VALUE, USER_ID, TRANS_TYPE_ID) AS
SELECT 10, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 3, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| USER_ID | SUM_TRANS_TYPE_1 | SUM_TRANS_TYPE_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 25 |
| 2 | 5 | 20 |
| 3 | 35 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R_08KLjt)

Comment: thank u, this "Use conditional aggregation:" worked, i really aprecciate it :)